# Docker: Can't connect to MySQL Container on local machine

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I am currently working on an api application together with Symfony.

My first step is to run a MySQL container to create the needed database.

I am using Docker-Compose in Version 3.9 and I want to install MySQL version 8+.

I wrote the needed environment arguments inside my .env:

```
MYSQL_DATABASE=swagger_api
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_PORT=3306
```

This is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  ### MySQL Container
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql_container
    hostname: mysql_container_host
    command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    build:
      context: ./
      args:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
        MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "${MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - mysql_alias
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:latest

MAINTAINER XXX <xxx@gmail.com>

RUN chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql

ARG MYSQL_DATABASE
ARG MYSQL_USER
ARG MYSQL_PASSWORD
ARG MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE = $MYSQL_DATABASE
ENV MYSQL_USER = $MYSQL_USER
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD = $MYSQL_PASSWORD
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD = $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

#if we need to import data from sql file

#ADD data.sql /etc/mysql/data.sql
#RUN sed -i 's/MYSQL_DATABASE/'$MYSQL_DATABASE'/g' /etc/mysql/data.sql
#RUN cp /etc/mysql/data.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

EXPOSE 3306
```

The container is up and running. I am using a machine with MacOS Version Ventura 13.0.1.

However, when I try to log in with the set credentials inside my database client, I receive this error:

[image: client]

When I enter the bash of my mysql_container and echo my before set enviroment variables, everything looks fine:
[image: bash]

What did I miss here? Any improvements or feedback? I basically want to use MySQL 8+ inside a container so I am able to connect from a client on the same machine

Comment: I was unable to find documentation for the answer. The issue is that Docker is predominantly a Linux solution and -- I think -- the daemon and containers run on a Linux VM on Mac OS systems. For this reason, containers aren't accessible on the Mac host's network (you're attempting to use localhost `127.0.0.1`). There is a way (which I can't find for you; not a Mac user) that gets you the IP address of a container so that you may access its ports.

Comment: Yes, you are right - I'd have to get the docker container's 'actual' ip in order to connect, after allowing connections from a local machine. Check my answer, this approach does not need this ugly workaround.

Comment: Your answer is probably the best approach.  Hard-coding the credentials and settings in a Dockerfile is inflexible and risks someone else who has the image retrieving those values.  The specific error in your current setup is the extra spaces in the `ENV` line, though.  If you can read the text in the last PNG file you can see equals signs at the start of the environment-variable values, which is caused by the extra whitespace.

Comment: @DavidMaze lmfao good catch! this was probably the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used now a different approach. For my usages, I don't need a Dockerfile, since I just want to set a default user and password (for now).

I changed my docker-compose.yml to this:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  ### MySQL Container
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql_container
    image: mysql:latest
    hostname: mysql_container_host
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "${MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - mysql_alias
```

For anyone using MacOS and don't need to customize the official image, this approach works as intended:

[image: db]

Comment: (You can further simplify this setup by deleting the `networks:`, `container_name:`, and `hostname:` Compose options.  None of them have any significant effect unless you've configured other clients in the same Compose file to use the `mysql_container` or `mysql_alias` names, and you should be able to change those to use the Compose service name `mysql` as a host name.)

Comment: @DavidMaze so having the service name 'mysql' defined is already enough to address it in the name space ?

Comment: Yes.  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.